# Why does this very simply piece of Python script not work? While not loop

Tags: python, list, loops, input, while-loop

Why does this very simply piece of Python script not work?

I'm familar with Java so I thought I would give Python a go...but why does this not work?

```
def playAgain(roundCounter):
    reply = ""
    replyList='y n'.split()
    if roundCounter == 1:
        print('Would you like to play again? Y/N')
        while not reply in replyList:
            reply = input().lower  
        if reply == 'y':
            roundCounter == 1
        elif reply == 'n':
            print('Thanks for playing! Bye!')
            sys.exit()
```

This should print "Would you like to play again?" and then keep requesting the users input until they type 'Y' or 'N'.

For some reason, it keeps looping over and over again though and won't break out of the loop - even if I type 'y' or 'n'.

It's such a simple piece of code I don't understand why it doesn't work - and in fact I used a near identical piece of code earlier on in my script and it worked fine!

Comment: Could you share the near identical piece of code? It would probably be easier to find the problem by spotting differences between the two.

Comment: This isn't related to the problem (which is solved in the answers), but to help the Java => Python transition a bit: You're doing too much work with `replyList='y n'.split()`. There's Python syntax to define a list (`replyList = ['y', 'n']`) which is cleaner. In case you do want a string (maybe it will be a parameter to the function), you can test for membership in a string just as in a list. So `reply_opts = 'yn'` and then `'y' in reply_opts` will evaluate to True.

Answer (score 8):

you forgot the parantheses:

```
reply = input().lower  # this returns a function instead of calling it
```

do this:

```
reply = input().lower()
```

Edit: As pointed by arshajii, you're also doing the assignment wrong:

```
if reply == 'y':
    roundCounter == 1  # change this to: roundCounter = 1
```

**==** is the equality operator and returns a boolean, assignment is done by **=**

Comment: This seems to be a bigger issue than the `==`, but you might want to add that to your answer as well for the sake of completeness (I deleted mine).

Comment: Grrrr its always the small things! Thank you! 

(You too arshajii for spotting my other mistake!)

Comment: @arshajii, Yes, note that `roundCounter` is already `1` anyway, so the whole `if reply == 'y'` is unnecessary.

Comment: Indeed - usually roundCounter is 6, but for the sake of testing my code I reduced it to 1!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def playAgain(roundCounter):
    reply = ""
    replyList='y n'.split()
    if roundCounter == 1:
        print('Would you like to play again? Y/N')
    while not reply in replyList:
        reply = input().lower()
    if reply == 'y':
        roundCounter = 1
    elif reply == 'n':
        print('Thanks for playing! Bye!')
        sys.exit()

playAgain(1)
```

Comment: As the asker of this question pointed out, he wants it to loop if the reply is not 'y' or 'n'. So your idea of moving the `if` and `elif` statements inside the `while` loop makes no sense. He only wants to check those conditions if the replies are actually in the `replyList`. They are perfectly fine left outside the `while` loop. Arsh Singh's answer to this question covers everything.